# How to index a site like mysitr.com/courses?id= in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search

I wanted to index this url in the google search `mysite.com/courses?id=123`. The problem is that I have wordpress installed and I cannot find a solution to this. Any kind help  is thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your permalink structure by going to Settings->permalinks and select a pretty url like the last one. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks